# Why powershell(ise) sometimes prints out the code I execute?

Tags: powershell, printing

The powershell ise sometimes prints out my source code, if I have:

```
function f
{
  $a=2
}
$a
```

It prints:

```
C:\Users\vics> function f
{
    $a=2
}
$a
```

Why so weired?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are not saving your files, the code is written down into the console window. If your file is saved, it is just executed. You will then see the execution path like

```
C:\Users\vics> C:\Users\vics\Documents\test.ps1
...
```